# How to sign raw transaction with eosjs?

Tags: transactions

Lets say I have a transaction like below:

```
var tx =     { transaction_id: 
'111ee28e5deca69e54dadf751eba8fae181f0ceafc601dcab92700f5200abef8',
      broadcast: false,
      transaction: 
       { compression: 'none',
         transaction: 
          { expiration: '2018-05-09T13:00:16',
            region: 0,
            ref_block_num: 19637,
            ref_block_prefix: 1895049749,
            max_net_usage_words: 0,
            max_kcpu_usage: 0,
            delay_sec: 0,
            context_free_actions: [],
            actions: [Array] },
         signatures: [] } }
```

Let's say `const privateKey = 5KBwtUpu6qMKysaUXswjQr1b3Rhdza2EftAUFQPi6wZpUdkcY13`

What is the specific process for signing this transaction? How are the fields encoded and what data is included in the transaction signature?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `eosjs-ecc` for signing easily.

If you want to sign a hash:

```
ecc.Signature.signHash(sha256hash, privateKey).toString()
```

If you want to sign something that isn't a hash:

```
ecc.sign(Buffer.from(someData, 'utf8'), privateKey)
```

---

**Edit**: The transaction itself will have to be serialized based on the ABI, packed and then signed. eosjs uses [fcbuffer](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs-fcbuffer) for that.

Comment: Great! Thanks. I will try this as soon as I get home. :))

Comment: But for signing an EOS Transaction, what is the input to the sign function?

Comment: @JohnHaager so that's a bit more in-depth. The transaction itself will have to be serialized based on the ABI, packed and then signed. eosjs uses [fcbuffer](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs-fcbuffer) for that.

Comment: @nsjames That's good info.  You should add it to your answer as it will help those who end up needing to implement transaction signing in languages other than JS.

Comment: @nsjames wait... so this will not generate a valid signature so that the transaction can be pushed to the blockchain with the produced signature? Sorry, I can't try this for myself atm since I'm not at home.

Comment: @cookiekid just signing the JSON you have posted will definitely fail. That is not in fact a valid action to push.

Out of curiousity, what is your goal?

Comment: @nsjames To sign raw transaction in the browser (without having to connect to another node/API service) so that it can be pushed to the blockchain at a later date. I can't use API because otherwise users in the browsers can DOS the API provider... Also, can't use backend to sign because otherwise their keys are exposed.

Comment: You shouldn't be deferring transactions locally. You can defer them within the contract and send them immediately. 

To answer the actual question though you would have to encode the transaction to a buffer, pack it accordingly and have the user sign it. There aren't enough characters in this comment to even get into how to do that.

Comment: does anyone has an example for what @nsjames explained? Maybe even in Scatter?

Answer (score 3):

To sign a transaction offline you can use eosjs. There is a configuration option

> broadcast [boolean=true] - post the transaction to the blockchain. Use false to obtain a fully signed transaction.

If you want to translate it to another language you need to convert the code from

- eos.transaction (https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs/blob/5107933dff1863a86a112889a1f65429b7537a07/src/write-api.js#L490),
- FcBuffer (as metioned already in some answers) and
- defaultSignProvider using ecc (https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs/blob/745603a982ded9781721c46a1209d98640527928/src/index.js#L192)

Answer (score 0):

I normally use it like this and eosjs signs it automatically.

```
eos.contract('currency').then(currency => {
 currency.transaction(cur => {
  cur.transfer('inita', 'initb', '1 CUR', '')
 })
})
```

If you want to sign it yourself i guess you should use [eosjs-ecc](https://github.com/eosio/eosjs-ecc#sign)

Comment: This still uses a third party api. I need to do it manually. I have seen eosjs-ecc but I am still unsure of what data actually needs to be signed. You can't sign an object unless it is converted to a string, buffer etc.

Comment: To do that manually I would check the EOSRPC Wallet `sign_transaction` endpoint. But I suggest you to have an instance of `keosd` and let it handle your keys, you could just call the `sign_transaction` out-of-the-box!

Comment: "This still uses a third party api". Does this mean you want to sign without using any existing library? If so maybe you should drop "eosjs" from the title.

Comment: No, sorry for confusion. I mean that using nanonano's method requires that you connect to a node. It has to be done without needing to.